# Bevel Node does not work in 4.0.2

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

The Bevel Node in Blender 4.0.2 just doesn't work and I can't figure out why.
I tried it on the Default Cube in 2.83.18 and it works just fine. But in Version 4.0.2 it just doesn't work.
Thanks in advance.
[image: Blender 2.83.18]

[image]

Comment: Try on a fresh install of Blender with default settings and no addons. If it works then, it may be a compatibility issue with your hardware (GPU)...

Comment: Works for me as well on Windows 11. Might be a  bug related to your hardware.  Are GPU drivers up to date?

Comment: Sadly, that didn't work. I updated my drivers and still get the same issue.